# Regex for multiple web links with no whitespace?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse a string that contains multiple YouTube links, but no white-space between them. The links can also start with "http" or "https". Example string:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123
```

So 3 links in there. I have no control over that string at all, as it comes from a chat service that people are posting links into and then it's my job to regex the URL's out and record them.

Here's the Regex I've come up with so far:

```
(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/\S+
```

I'm not sure how to make it break when it sees a pattern further down the string though. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "*break* when it sees"? Do you mean Brake/stop or pick up another HTTP link in added text? If there is more text, added it to the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Regex which will split out the joined links. Note that I have renamed the links to 111, 222 and 333 for easier debugging:

```
string data = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc111http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc222https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc333";

string pattern = @"(?<YouTubeLink>https?.+?)(?=http|$)";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Groups["YouTubeLink"].Value);

/* The above results in an IEnumerable of these strings:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc111
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc222
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc333
*/
```

Explanation:

> - `(?< > )` : Named match capture for easier post regex processing data extraction.
> - `s?`      : To capture http and the `s` is optional `?` for https
> - `.+?`     : capture as minimal as possible
> - `(?=  )`  : Look ahead, to stop the `.+?` from grabbing more text.
> - `http|$`  : look ahead to stop on a new http or end of the data.

Answer (score 4):

You can just split on `http` and then add it back:

```
var input = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc123";

var split = input.Split("http");

var urls = split.Select(x => "http" + x);
```

This of course assumes that "http" doesn't appear anywhere else in the urls...

Comment: Very pragmatic, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a separator of some kind, like a `"|"`, when you created the string, then you could easily split on that.

```
var videoUrls = input.Split("|");
```

Comment: I don't think that's a given, he was non-specific about where this string is coming from.

Comment: Sorry guys, here now. I have no control over that link at all as it comes from a chat service that people are posting links in to and then it's my job to regex the URL's out and record them.

Comment: Then the best way is probably to split on "http://" to avoid an extra entry if a url has "http" in it somewhere.